# Notification Panel

Tags: notification

What do you think is the best way to present a standard notification panel in a system to the user?

Widely adopted is the 100% width bar at the top of the page with an icon. Generally this bar is green for notifications and red for error, validation etc, depending on what kind of message you're trying send.

There are other options like modal pop-ups or simple javascript alerts/confirm, but I'd like to know if there is another more innovative approach to this.

Comment: Why do you need a notification to be 'innovative'? What is wrong with the javascript alert or a top of the page flash alert? We can't just give you a list of examples as there isn't a 'correct' one. However if you have a specific situation you need to know how to display the alert then we can probably help there, but not if you just want to know loads of different types of alerts as that is just a never-ending list of examples.

Comment: @JonW in most scenarios there are some cases where a specific approach may work such as alerts or notifications, but I feel like a 100% width notification bar in some cases could pass unobserved and sending alerts to the user each time that the user have an interaction with the system (or at least very often) could be annoying, I'm just wondering if there an alternative idea, maybe a concept, I got a couple in my head, but I haven't implemented anyone yet, so I'm just looking for some kind of other approaches as an inspiration, as you wrote there's no a good or bad way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The UX SE is for "answerable" questions](https://ux.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask), but there is no one answer here--**it simply depends on what your goals are**. Modal windows require immediate action and block other usage until they are closed. Is that necessary or useful for your application?

[**Here's a relevant dribbble**](http://dribbble.com/search?page=2&q=notification) search if you're just looking for inspiration.